# How do I show something only for a parent segment and not it's children?

Tags: conditional

How do I display something only for one of the parent Structure sections and not others or this sections children?
I was thinking of using

```
{% if craft.request.segment(2) == 'modules' and craft.request.lastSegment|length %}''
```

but that still shows for its children.

Comment: Is this being output inside a nav of your structure or on a structure entry page?

Comment: Yes Luke this is basically a nav for a structure where I wan't to display something differently only when on one of the parents url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lastSegment will always have length whether it's 2, 3, 4 etc. I am unclear about your Structure setup, but if there is nothing after "modules", "modules" is the last segment and therefore exists.

So maybe something like:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == 'modules' and not craft.request.getSegment(3)|length %}
```

Comment: Thank you for setting me on the right track. I was able to accomplish what I wanted with the following.
`{% if craft.request.getSegment(2) == 'modules' and not craft.request.getSegment(3)|length %}`

Comment: I added "not" to the answer above that I had originally left out.